# SAS Drive Upgrade

Tags: hp, sas, raid1

We have a HP Proliant server with a RAID 1 disk ( 2x 146Gb 15K SAS) configuration. The logical drive is full and I would like to expand it.

1. I've purchased 2 x 300GB 15K SAS to replace the 146K
2. Operating System: Windows Server 2012

Any advice on how how to replace the drives without losing data?

I have attached the RAID configuration's screen print.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPYVr.png)

Answer (score 5):

1. Do backup of the whole RAID1 volume.
2. Replace drives and create a new RAID1
3. Restore backup to "new" RAID1 volume